# extract value from field in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the output to be what the user types in to the input field but it says "undefined" when I press submit. Why is this and how do I fix it, Thanks

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").value;
}
```

```html
<form id="input" action="/action_page.php">
  input: <input type="text" name="input"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>

<p id="output"></p>
```

I got it, i had 2 things with the same id

Comment: Have you researched how to get values from a form?

Comment: Yes and I couldn't find out how

Comment: Hint: `getElementById` requires an `id` field with that value. `name` is different.

Comment: all the places i've read on siad you just do .value

Comment: you don't have "2 things with the same id" because name is different from id, but `getElementById("input")` gets the <form> element and it doesn't have a `.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an `id` to your input field and not the form. Or you need to create a new id for the input field.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").value;
}
```

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  input: <input type="text" name="input" id="input"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>

<p id="output"></p>
```

You could also use selectors `#input > [type=text]` like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#input > [type=text]").value;
}
```

```html
<form id="input" action="/action_page.php">
  input: <input type="text" name="input"><br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit">
</form>

<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: the name is for naming the data that will be sent the id is for giving the element a dom id

Comment: Thanks, I see now that I had 2 things with the same ID and that was causing the problem, thanks for the help, I'll accept your answer in a few minutes whens i can

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to get the value of element whose id is input as per the javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("input").value
```

Now the **form** has this id, so it is giving you **undefined**. 
Assign another id to your `input type="text"` and use it in `document.getElementById("input").value` , your code will work fine

Comment: Could also navigate to it like `document.getElementById("input").input`.